# change run 64 bit run time property to false on run time executing ssis package through sql server job

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, sql-job, ssis-connection-manager

I have parent package and associated child package to be executed from sql server agent job but I am getting following error :
*

> Source: xxxxx  Connection manager "RedshiftODBC"     Description: An
>   ODBC error -1 has occurred.  End Error Code: 0xC0014009     Source:
>   xxxxxx Test Connection manager "RedshiftODBC"     Description: There
>   was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC)
>   connection with the database server.  End Error  Error: 2018-09-13
>   09:40:02.59     Code: 0x0000020F     Source: Load xxxxxx from RedShift
>   Load xxxxxx table [6]     Description: The AcquireConnection method
>   call to the connection manager RedshiftODBC failed with error code
>   0xC0014009

*.
I have check marked  Run32bitRuntime on sql job execution option but still not able to resolve.

help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Hi there several steps to run a SSIS package in 32 bits:

1. Check if ODBC is created in 32 bit. Real odbc 32 bit administrator is in folder C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
2. Check if SSIS package has chekded run64bitruntime property FALSE.
3. Check if SQL Agent property 'Use 32 bit runtime' checked.